# What does A=[x; y'] in Matlab mean?

Tags: matlab

I'm learning Matlab and I see a line that I don't understand:

`A=[x; y']`

What does it mean? ' usually means the transponate but I don't know what ; means in the vector. Can you help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [ ] indicates create a matrix.
The ; indicates that the first vector is on the first line, and that the second one is on the second line.
The ' indicates the transponate.
Exemple :

```
>> x = [1,2,3,4]
x = 
    1 2 3 4

>> y = [5;6;7;8]
y =
    5
    6
    7
    8

>> y'
ans =
    5 6 7 8

>> A = [x;y']
A = 
    1 2 3 4
    5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 7):

`[x y]` means horizontal cat of the vectors, while `[x;y]` means vertical.

For example (Horizontal cat):

```
x = [1
     2
     3];

y = [4 
     5 
     6];

[x y] =  [1 4
          2 5 
          3 6];
```

(Vertical cat):

```
  x = [1 2 3];
  y = [4 5 6];

 [x; y] = 
      [1 2 3;
       4 5 6];
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to be clear, in MATLAB `'` is the *complex conjugate* transpose. If you want the non-conjugating transpose, you should use `.'`.

Comment: Imaginary numbers are just in your head. For real things, `'` works just fine.

Comment: You can probably infer that I've written too many implementations of TRANSPOSE and CTRANSPOSE ;)

Answer (score 4):

It indicates the end of a row when creating a matrix from other matrices.

For example

```
X = [1 2];
Y = [3,4]';
A = [X; Y']
```

gives a matrix

```
A = [ 1 2 ]
    [ 3 4 ]
```

This is called vertical concatenation which basically means forming a matrix in row by row fashion from other matrices (like the example above). And yes you are right about `'` indicating the transpose operator. As another example you could use it to create a transposed vector as follows

```
Y = [1 2 3 4 5];
X = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
Y = Y';
```

Comparing the above you will see that X is now equal to Y. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Let set the size of x m*n (m rows and n columns) and the size of y n*p.
Then A is the matrix formed by the vertical concatenation of x and the transpose of y (operator '), and its size is (m+p)*n. The horizontal concatenation is done with comma instead of semi-column.
This notation is a nice shorthand for function vertcat.
See http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html for more information

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon ' ; ' is used to start a new row.

e.g. x=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] means

```
    x= 1 2 3 
       4 5 6
       7 8 9
```

So if u take x=[1 2 3; 4 5 6] and y=[7 8 9]'

then z=[x; y'] means

```
    z= 1 2 3 
       4 5 6
       7 8 9
```